# How to use AWS Lambda to run as background task for a limited of time?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, mqtt

What I am trying to do is to trigger lambda to run as a background for a limited amount of time (less than limited lambda timeout). I use setInterval and setTimeout but they don't work properly with async/await. Note that the code works if running locally as a node app. I have my code as below:

```
const mqtt = require('async-mqtt');

module.exports.startPolling = function(event, context, callback) {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false
    let runInterval = setInterval( async() => {
    await run("tram", "#");
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(runInterval)}, 5000); 
}


const run = async(mode, route) => {  
  console.log("Starting");
    try {
        client = await mqtt.connectAsync('mqtts://mqtt.hsl.fi:8883/');
        await client.subscribe(`/hfp/v2/journey/+/vp/${mode}/${route}`); 
        response = await getMessageAsync(client, "message");
        console.log(response.toString());
        await client.end();
        console.log("Done");
    } catch (e){
        console.log(e.stack);
        process.exit();
    }
}

const getMessageAsync = (client, ...args) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.on(...args, (topic, message) => {
      resolve(message);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: What's the problem/what's not working as expected?

Comment: If you need to periodically run some code then have a look at triggering your lambda using a CloudWatch event. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html

Comment: @404 now it actually works! that's really weird as it didn't work properly before! thanks for answer

Comment: @BenTse cloudwatch event can trigger only from at least every 1mn.

Comment: Use the bluebird module which offers Promise.delay, which can be awaited. Your code will be easier to follow.

Comment: i believe this design is an anti-pattern, your code is passive, you start it to listen for events; lambda is itself event-based and is ideally automatically triggered _per-event_ with sns or alike. when you do what you are showing, you have two problem, when there is no event, your code is non-productive but you have to pay; on the other hand if there is too much event, your program/lambda cant keep up. you should really be looking to align with aws and fully adopt event-based paradigm.

Comment: Thank you guys for the comment! I have fixed this issue. Basically, it was more like a problem of not using mqtt library correctly. The idea of using mqtt is to continuously get the pushed event from server after subscribe to mqtt topic. Now I am able to get continuous push from server, which I am no longer need setInterval inside lambda. I also knew that it wasn't efficient to use it inside lambda but it was just quick solve to my main problem (unable to continuously get message from mqtt server).